# I need help figuring out whats wrong with the program

Tags: python

```
# 5/26/21, Python Project 

def main():
    answer = input("Would you like to take a quiz? (yes or no)")

    if(answer == "yes"):

        input("Do you have a favorite televison show? (yes or no)")
        
        if(answer == "yes"):
        
            favShow = input("What is your favorite television show?")
        
        print("Your favorite television show is " + favShow + ".")
        
        input("Did you like this quiz? (yes or no)")
        
        if(answer == "yes"):
        
        print("Thank you")
        
    else:

        print("Goodbye")

main()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! `print("Thank you")` needs to be indented and some `input` return values are never set to anything. `print("Your favorite television show is " + favShow + ".")` needs to be indented because `favShow` may not be initialized. But in general, please tell us what behavior you expect and what you're getting. Also, please choose a relevant, descriptive technical title. Thanks.

Comment: Please describe what you see that is wrong and what you expected to happen. I can see one indentation error and one semantic error, for instance.

Comment: Okay so the program is supposed to have four questions for the user to answer and it does but it does not run properly and when I run the program with Python IDLE it says I have an error on line 20. Does anyone know what I am supposed to do to fix that? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please review the guidelines on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Following these guidelines will help your question receive more attention and receive more and better answers.

Comment: Can you show the error that you receive? Would help with an accurate diagnosis.

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign the result of the `input` function calls to the value you are checking in the if statements. This code should do what you require.

```
def main():
    answer = input("Would you like to take a quiz? (yes or no)")
    if(answer == "yes"):
        answer = input("Do you have a favorite televison show? (yes or no)")
        if(answer == "yes"):
            favShow = input("What is your favorite television show?")
            print("Your favorite television show is " + favShow + ".")
        
        answer = input("Did you like this quiz? (yes or no)")
        if(answer == "yes"):
            print("Thank you")
        else:
            print("Goodbye")

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You neglected to indent your nested `if` statement. Also, you neglected to store the `input("Do you have a favorite televison show? (yes or no)")` and `input("Did you like this quiz? (yes or no)")` into the `answer` variable. Finally, although this is optional, you can also remove the redundant brackets. Try:

```
def main():
    answer = input("Would you like to take a quiz? (yes or no)")
    if answer == "yes":
        answer = input("Do you have a favorite televison show? (yes or no)")
        if answer == "yes":
            favShow = input("What is your favorite television show?")
            print("Your favorite television show is " + favShow + ".")
        answer = input("Did you like this quiz? (yes or no)")
        if answer == "yes":
            print("Thank you")
    else:
        print("Goodbye")

main()
```

Test run:

```
Would you like to take a quiz? (yes or no)yes
Do you have a favorite televison show? (yes or no)no
Did you like this quiz? (yes or no)yes
Thank you
```